# awk script: find and print max value and file name containing max value

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I am trying to find a file with in a dir that contains the largest number (at position 3rd row 3rd column). I want both the max value and the file name containing max value printed. This is what i have right now

```
find ./ -name sample-file\* -exec sed '3!d' {} \; | awk '{print $3}' | awk 'n<$1{n=$1}END{print n}'
```

This gets me the max value, but i also want the file name containing the max value. Print along with this.

Current output:

When run for dir1:

```
487987
```

When run for dir2:

```
9879889
```

I want the output to be like this

when run for dir1:

```
file16    487987
```

when run for dir2:

```
file23    9879889
```

Appreciate some inputs on this. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

awk script:

```
BEGIN {
    n = 0
    fn = ""
}

(FNR == 3) && ($3 > n) {
    n = $3
    fn = FILENAME
}

END {
    printf "%s: %s\n", fn, n
}
```

use as `awk -f <file.awk> sample-file*`.

Could probably be more efficient with `nextfile` after the `fn` assignment in the FNR block or similar mechanisms to short-circuit the rest of the other lines in each input file.

zcat and shell

```
declare n=0 fn=
for i in sample-file*; do
    t=$(zcat "$i" | awk 'NR == 3 {print $3; exit}')
    if [ $t -gt $n ]; then
        n=$t
        fn=$i
    fi
done
echo "$fn: $n"
```

Comment: awesome this what i was expecting, thanks. I actually am ssh'ing into a host and reading the contents so i cant have the awk script there. is it possible to pass the contents of the input file (file being read from the remote host) instead of the file name (to the awk command)?

Comment: I have worked it out with a temp workaround by scp the awk file, but would like to know if this can be done through "cat file | awk -f program.awk ". Thanks.

Comment: Also How can the awk script be used with compressed files, like i have a bunch of .gz files that need to be awked for the same reason.

Comment: The problem with your ssh file input comment (and the gzip files comment) is that if you can't give awk the files as files then it doesn't have the file names to use later. If you need to work on file contents only then I don't know that you can do what you want as easily and it might make more sense to turn this into a shell script over a set of files instead of an awk one.